# SMS Receiver - Force closes everytime I receive a sms

Tags: java, android, gps, sms

I am trying to create a phone locator using SMS as an activator, but when I'm sending a sms to the phone, the application always crashes(force close):

Here is my code for the class:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        private static final String FAR_MODE_KEY = "farmode";
        private String FarModeKeyword;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            prefs = getSharedPreferences(Keywords, MODE_PRIVATE);
            FarModeKeyword = prefs.getString(FAR_MODE_KEY, "");

            //---get the SMS message passed in---
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String message = "";
            String number = "";
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
                {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    message += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                }

                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
                {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    number += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                }

            }

            if (message == FarModeKeyword)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String loc = "";
                loc = getLocation();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        loc,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendSMS(number, loc);
            }

        }

        private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
        }

        private String getLocation ()
        {
            // Get the location manager
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria ();
            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

            LocationListener MyLocListener = new loc_listener();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 1000, 1, MyLocListener); 

            String add = "";

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try 
            {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat,lon, 1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0)
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                    add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            locationManager.removeUpdates(MyLocListener);
            return add;

        }

        public class loc_listener implements LocationListener
        {     
              public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
                  lat = l.getLatitude();
                  lon = l.getLongitude();         
              }
              public void onProviderEnabled(String p) {
              }

              public void onProviderDisabled(String p) {
              }

              public void onStatusChanged(String p, int status, Bundle extras){
              }      
        }
    }
```

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="locateodroid.james"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="locateodroid.james.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBBo4h4fDksXasHd7iCgIg0A5wTriToW8w"/>

     <permission
          android:name="locateodroid.james.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="locateodroid.james.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            class="locateodroid.james.receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="locateodroid.james.sms.SMSReceiver"
            class="locateodroid.james.sms.SmsReceiver"
            android:label="SMSReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat of error:

```
    02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver locateodroid.james.sms.SMSReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: locateodroid.james.sms.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/locateodroid.james-1.apk]
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1773)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: locateodroid.james.sms.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/locateodroid.james-1.apk]
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1764)
02-05 04:03:25.169: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  ... 10 more
```

I'm working on this error for almost 2 days and still I've got no answer for this, can someone help me on this matter? THANKS IN ADVANCE!

**UPDATE**

The first problem was now resolved, but another error aries, a NullPointerException is throwned when I received a sms

```
package locateodroid.james;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String FarModeKeyword;
    private String Keywords = "prefmode";
    private Double lat;
    private Double lon;
    private static final String FAR_MODE_KEY = "farmode";
    private Context con;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context,
                "test",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        con = context;
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(Keywords, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        FarModeKeyword = prefs.getString(FAR_MODE_KEY, "");

        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String message = "";
        String number = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                message += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }

            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                number += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            }

        }

        if (message == FarModeKeyword)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String loc = "";
            loc = getLocation();
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    loc,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sendSMS(number, loc);
        }

    }

    private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String keywords2,
            int modePrivate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

    private String getLocation ()
    {
        // Get the location manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria ();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        LocationListener MyLocListener = new loc_listener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 1000, 1, MyLocListener); 

        String add = "";

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(con, Locale.getDefault());
        try 
        {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat,lon, 1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0)
            {
                for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        locationManager.removeUpdates(MyLocListener);
        return add;

    }

    private LocationManager getSystemService(String locationService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public class loc_listener implements LocationListener
    {     
          public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
              lat = l.getLatitude();
              lon = l.getLongitude();         
          }
          public void onProviderEnabled(String p) {
          }

          public void onProviderDisabled(String p) {
          }

          public void onStatusChanged(String p, int status, Bundle extras) {
          }      
    }
}
```

The class is returning a NullPointerException error now :(

Comment: Add the stack trace of the exception

Comment: I'm testing in on the actual phone so I cannot post a stack trace of the exception, my AVD is hanging at the moment so I cannot use it

Comment: No stack trace = no idea - but there is one thing wrong, and that's that you're doing way too much work in `onReceive()`. Do your work in a new thread.

Comment: I'll try to make my AVD work to get a stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Its unable to find the class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: locateodroid.james.sms.SMSReceiver
```

Are you sure about the package reference?

This is likely coming from the class line in your receiever:

```
class="locateodroid.james.sms.SmsReceiver"
```

### update

The reason you can't those context properties is because they are **STATIC** constants

meaning that you grab them from the base class (without the need for an instance) like so:

```
Context.MODE_PRIVATE
```

Comment: The class is "public class SMSReceiver", what is the right thing to do?

Comment: The class is also located on my MainActivity.java because of the getSharedPrefences always produce an error when I put it on a separate .java/class file

Comment: i'd recommend separating them, I know that is not causing the issue. but your methods for retrieve the preference is meaning that you did something wrong when retrieving your preference values.

Comment: I've searched that getSharedPrefences can only be used under Activities, unless you pass on the likes of parameters. I'm still new at developing an android app, actually this is my first app.

Comment: Are you sure about that James? I believe otherwise.

Comment: I've just copied and pasted the whole class into another .java file ( copying all the necessary codes ) but there's still an error about the getSharedPreferences ( specifically in the MODE_PRIVATE )

Comment: Sorry, but I'm just really new in Android development, hope you understand :)

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of what happens when you try this?

Comment: Now, I know what really causes the error, I really need to put it in a separate file. But my next problem is the shared preferences and the geocoder

Comment: I get this errors:

MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable;
LOCATION_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable;
context cannot be resolved to a variable(on geocoder)

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro, I'm gonna try to run again my code to see if it's really working. You're a big help to me bro, this app has been really stressful to me :(

Comment: I now have a NullPointerException on that code bro :( just copied the whole text to a new java file

Comment: Try adding logs to find out what is null and then figure out why its null. Or just post the stacktrace, but you should be fixing your own NPE's (Null Pointer Exception).